# Dockerを使用したプロジェクトの進め方に関する質問です。

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

質問は２つあります！よろしくお願いします！

今、ubuntuコンテナの中にLAMP環境を構築しようとしているのですが、流れとして以下のような感じで行こうと思っているのですが、⑤以降の作業の進め方がわかりません。Gitで言うところのmergeの作業は、Dockerではどうすればいいのですか？

1. Ubuntuコンテナの中にLAMP環境を構築する
2. 1で作ったコンテナをイメージ化する
3. 2で作ったイメージをメンバーに配る
4. メンバーは3で配られたイメージからコンテナを生成する
5. メンバーは4で生成したコンテナの中で作業する

このあと、どのようにイメージを一つに統合すればいいのですか？

また、上記の1でコンテナを構築する際に

```
service start apache2
```

などとしている場合、上記の5で作業する際、再度上記のコマンドを実行する必要はないのですか？（イメージからコンテナを生成すれば、そのイメージのもととなるコンテナの設定は全て引き継がれる？？？）

以上よろしくお願いします。。

Answer (score 0):

有名なミドルウェアを作るのでしたら、既存のM/W ごとの image を利用し、それらを docker-compose でつなぎ合わせる、という風にするのがよいと思います。今回でしたら、 LAMP ですので、 MySQL イメージと apache イメージでしょうか。

また、 docker でプロセス実行する際には、普通の linux 上でのミドルウェアの起動方式である、サービス登録・起動での取り扱いではなく、サーバー本体を直接実行するようなスクリプトを記述し、それをエントリーポイントにする、が一般的だと思います。

例えば、 [apache のdocker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) では、そのような構成になっている模様です。 参考: https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile